# how to troubleshoot ctags with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm kicking the tires on Sublime Text 2 to see if I should switch to using it longer term. One key feature I need to have in order to switch to it is to be able to jump to symbol definitions in my code with a hot-key.

I see that there is a ctags plugin for ST2 which is perfect for what I'm looking for. I've installed the plugin but for some reason it doesn't work. I get no response when I try jumping with ctrl+alt+], ctrl+alt+[, or ctrl+alt+left_click.

Since I'm still new to ST2 I don't know where to even start with troubleshooting my problem. Is there a debug console or something that I can look at to get more information on why it isn't working? Any tips to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

BTW, my ST2 installation is on Windows 7.

Comment: I've continued playing around with it since my initial post and found that the default key bindings of ctrl+t,ctrl+t, and ctrl+t,ctrl+b do work so the plugin is mostly functional. It's only the alternate bindings using the '[' and']' keys that are not working. I'm glad it's at least basically functional now but I'm still curious as to why the alternate bindings are not working.

Comment: Please comment or follow this issue on Github at: https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

According to [Sublime Text 2's docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-python-console-and-the-python-api)

> To open the Python console, press Ctrl+` or select View | Show Console
>   in the menu.